# std::list push_back() and pop_front() giving a const error

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on a coding project and have hit a bit of a snag. When I try to make it, I get these errors:

```
src/mean.cc:26:12: error: passing ‘const csce240::Mean’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   pop_back();
            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/list:63:0,
                 from inc/mean.h:9,
                 from src/mean.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_list.h:1152:7: note:   in call to ‘void std::__cxx11::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::pop_back() [with _Tp = double; _Alloc = std::allocator<double>]’
       pop_back() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^~~~~~~~
src/mean.cc:33:29: error: passing ‘const csce240::Mean’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   push_front(tempList.back());
                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/list:63:0,
                 from inc/mean.h:9,
                 from src/mean.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_list.h:1067:7: note:   in call to ‘void std::__cxx11::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_front(const value_type&) [with _Tp = double; _Alloc = std::allocator<double>; std::__cxx11::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = double]’
       push_front(const value_type& __x)
       ^~~~~~~~~~
```

The closest solution I could find was to add const to the end of the function definition, however that was already in the definition to start with. Here is are the .h and .cc files:

```
// Copyright 2019 Ian McDowell
#ifndef _CSCE240_HW_HW6_INC_MEAN_H //NOLINT
#define _CSCE240_HW_HW6_INC_MEAN_H //NOLINT

/* This class inherits from the Statistic class such that it may be used
 * polymorphically.
 */
#include <statistic.h>
#include <list>

namespace csce240 {

class Mean : public std::list<double>, public Statistic {
 public:

  /* Stores data (datum) such than an average may be calculated.
   * - NOTE: You do not necessarily need to store each datum.
   */
  void Collect(double datum);

  /* Returns the mean of the data (datum) from the Collect method.
   */
  double Calculate() const;
};

} // namespace csce240

#endif //NOLINT
```

----------------------Mean.cc-----------------------------

```cpp
// Copyright 2019 Ian McDowell
#include <mean.h>
using std::list;

namespace csce240 {

void Mean::Collect(double datum) {
    push_front(datum);
}

double Mean::Calculate() const {
    list<double> tempList;
    int i = 0;
    double temp;
    double avg = 0;

    while (!empty()) {
        temp = back();
        avg += temp;
        tempList.push_front(temp);
        pop_back();
        ++i;
    }

    avg = avg / i;

    while(!tempList.empty()) {
        push_front(tempList.back());
        tempList.pop_back();
    }

    return avg;
}


} // namespace csce240
```

Comment: please include code in the question.

Comment: ...and as you already have a solution it is unclear what is your question

Comment: You attempt to `pop_back()` in `Calculate()`, which is declared as `const`. You can't modify the current object from a `const` method.

Comment: Unrelated. Prefer [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Answer (score 5):

You're attempting to call `this->pop_back()` and `this->push_back()`, respectively, within a `const` method.

Remove the `const` qualifier from `Mean::Calculate()` [and the code will compile](https://godbolt.org/z/wTxbb_).